# How to Limit Nested navigation property in Asp.net mvc Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, navigation-properties, subquery

I Get A record from database with entity framework. it have Nested navigation Property .

```
  public partial class Comment
{
    public Comment()
    {
        this.Comments1 = new HashSet<Comment>();
    }

    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment Comment1 { get; set; }
}
```

Relation Between Id And Parent Id. and my navigation is Comments1 .
Now I select a Record that have 5 Nested Navigation . i want  limit Only to 3 Nested Navigation in my controller With C# Code. How to create a recursive Method and limit Nested Navigation to 3 Level ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that feature doesn't exist in EF. What you can do is disable lazy loading:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public YourContext() 
    { 
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    } 
}
```

And then use `Include` extension method as part of your query to load the levels that you need:

```
var query=context.Comments.Include(c=>Comments1.Select(c1=>c1.Comments1))...;
```

I think another solution could be using **Automapper**, if my mind doesn't fail me I think you can use `MaxDepth` method in self reference properties to specify how many levels you want to load:

```
 configuration.CreateMap<Comment, CommentViewModel>()
              .ForMember(dest => dest.Comments, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Comments1).MaxDepth(3)...;
```